# CesiumJS Running without 3D

Tags: cesiumjs

We are planning on replacing *OpenLayers* with *CesiumJS*, however, we cannot be 100% sure our clients are going to have robust-enough video cards to support *WebGL*. We are only planning on using *CesiumJS's* 2D mapping features, is there a way to get around having a video card with *WebGL* (or *OpenGL*) capabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Cesium is based solely on WebGL, and requires it.  But there's a fork called [TerriaJS](https://github.com/TerriaJS/terriajs) that uses Leaflet as its 2D fallback for non-WebGL systems.  TerriaJS was built for [Australia's National Map](http://nationalmap.gov.au/), and can be installed via npm.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I was afraid that was the case... I'll check out TerriaJS.